# Reading Current Transformer using Arduino

Tags: arduino, current, transformer, datalogger

I want to be able to read current using an Arduino. I have purchased a Hobut Current Transformer from Farnell (Element14): http://uk.farnell.com/hobut/ctscmicro19-150-5-t/transformer-current-150a-1-5va/dp/2448032?ost=2448032

Here is a link to the datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1850577.pdf

Could someone point me in the right direction to reading current using this current transformer and an Arduino?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

First hit on googling "interfacing CT to arduino": -

[image]

The current transformer you have will need the correct value burden resistor but everything else remains pretty much as standard.

[Here](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/buildingblocks/ct-sensors-interface) is a link to the page I stole the diagram from. There are quite a few suitable looking hits from what I googled like [this](http://www.homautomation.org/2013/09/17/current-monitoring-with-non-invasive-sensor-and-arduino/).

Comment: @JosephFTaylor if you are happy with this answer please consider formally accepting it else please ask what you need clarification on.